# Too many import statement at home page when initializing the framework

Tags: angularjs

In my angular project, I am planning to have a separate .js file for each page and a separate .js file for each service.

However, as I begin to code, I realized that I have a lot of  import statement in my index.html. This would cause user having to load all the .js file even if they might not need it.

An example of the .js for my index.html

```
<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/app.js" ></script>

<!-- controllers --> 
<script src="js/app/controllers/roomController.js"></script> 
<script src="js/app/controllers/dashBoardController.js"></script>

<!-- services --> 
<script src="js/app/services/dashBoardService.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/services/roomService.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/services/chatService.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/services/videoService.js"></script>
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

It's really a best practice to have each controller, each service, each directive… in a separate file, so you're doing it in the right way.

However, as you notice, it's better for the user (and for the server!) to download a minimal number of files. Your `index.html` is fine for development, but in production, you must compress all your files in in one, typically with a tool like [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) or [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/).

Comment: Even if you compress and concat all the .js file, it still require user to load all the javascript files. I am looking more towards a solution that only load the required js file at each page.

Comment: You've missed the `in one` part of the sentence ;) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, especially with large projects. A viable solution is using [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org) . You can find plenty of resources on the web about that, for instance you can try [this](https://github.com/reefat/angular-seed).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem so decided to use RequireJS to allow on-demand loading of my angularJS scripts.  I created a wrapper called `angularAMD` that hopefully can help you integrate RequireJS and AngularJS:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/